# Undefined method 'assert_select_email' in ActionMailer tests [Rails 3.2.13]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, actionmailer

I'm getting the following error when trying to use `assert_select_email` in my mailer tests:

```
undefined method `assert_select_email' for ...
```

The TestClass inherits from `< ActionMailer::TestCase` and
other assertions such as 'assert_equal` work.

As documented here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select_email

I set

```
 ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
```

Any ideas?
Oh, I'm using

- Rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because it's not in [ActionMailer::TestCase](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionMailer/TestCase)

Do you want [assert_emails](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionMailer/TestHelper/assert_emails)?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably include `ActionDispatch::Assertions::SelectorAssertions` in the test class. Like so:

```
UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  include ActionController::Assertions::SelectorAssertions

  # …
end
```

Then you should be able to use `assert_select_email`.